# What are some simple cases where "closure" can be best demonstrated in javaScript

Tags: javascript, closures, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

I still battle with the concept of closure and when I need to implement it.  I usually get there after trial and error, but I feel if I had some simplified representations of it's use with a clear explanation, I could preempt rewriting scripts to include it. Does anyone want to take a shot at clearing up an often confusing concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nathan's Lessons](http://nathansjslessons.appspot.com/) may clear up your confusions, if you are looking for simple explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```
 for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
 {
     setTimeout(function()
     {
         alert(j);
     }, 1000);
 }
```

A closure wraps the reference to the variable so it can access it when the function is invoke. In the above example, every call captures the same reference to j; ergo all functions capture the same reference and all will alert '10'. Now consider this example:

```
 for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
 {
     var innerReference = j;
     setTimeout(function()
     {
         alert(innerReference);
     }, 1000);
 }
```

In this example, each iteration of the loop captures the reference to the newly created 'innerReference' variable; and each iteration creates a new `innerReference`. Ergo, this time they display 1, 2, 3, 4, etc and so forth.

At a basic level, it's pretty much like this; a closure is the capture of a reference to another variable outside to what would normally be the scope of that object.

Comment: I hate to niggle, but when I plug your second example into a webpage and test it (in IE8), it doesn't do what you'd hoped....

Comment: Interesting. You certainly are correct. I'd definitely take a look at @suhair's link